# execution time is very high, how to reduce it

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g, query-optimization

We have a table in our production database. 
And it's size arround 220 gb
When I am performing following query specified here
Here with dummy scenario is taking to much time. 
Can we reduce the time of below query.

Help will be highly appreciated.

```
DELETE FROM testcpy1_bkp
WHERE    (num, dt, cd) IN (  SELECT num, dt, 899
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt
HAVING MAX (cd) != 899 OR MIN (cd) != 899)
OR (    (num, dt, cd) IN
(  SELECT num, dt, MAX (cd)
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt
HAVING MAX (cd) = 899 AND MIN (cd) = 899)
AND ROWID NOT IN (  SELECT MIN (ROWID)
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt
HAVING MAX (cd) = 899 AND MIN (cd) = 899));


DELETE FROM testcpy1_bkp t1
WHERE ROWID NOT IN
(SELECT MAX (ROWID)
FROM testcpy1_bkp t2
WHERE t1.num = t2.num AND t1.dt = T2.DT AND t1.cd = t2.cd);
```

Comment: *size of table on disk* is not a useful metric. Whereas *how many rows* is. Also how many rows meet your filtering criteria. What indexes do you have? What is the execution plan?  Query tuning is all about the details. If you read some of the other [questions on SO about query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+query-optimization) you should start to understand why your question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are performing a number of lookups against the same table that you are deleting from. Based on your information, I assume that this is a very large table. This makes the lookups expensive.

I would try picking out the subqueries from the WHERE clause in your DELETE statement and select these values into temporary tables, and then afterwards performing your DELETE statement based on the values in the temporary tables. This should speed up your query performance significantly.

It would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTestCPY1
SELECT num, dt, 899 AS cd
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt
HAVING MAX (cd) != 899 OR MIN (cd) != 899

INSERT INTO #TempTestCPY2
SELECT num, dt, MAX (cd) AS cd
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt
HAVING MAX (cd) = 899 AND MIN (cd) = 899

INSERT INTO #TempTestCPY3
SELECT MIN (ROWID) AS ROWID
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt
HAVING MAX (cd) = 899 AND MIN (cd) = 899

DELETE FROM testcpy1_bkp
WHERE
    (num, dt, cd) IN 
        (SELECT num, dt, cd FROM #TempTestCPY1)
    OR ((num, dt, cd) IN
        (SELECT num, dt, cd FROM #TempTestCPY2)
        AND ROWID NOT IN 
        (SELECT ROWID FROM #TempTestCPY3));

INSERT INTO #TempTestCPY4
SELECT MAX (ROWID) ROWID
FROM testcpy1_bkp
GROUP BY num, dt, cd

DELETE FROM testcpy1_bkp t1
WHERE ROWID NOT IN
(SELECT ROWID FROM #TempTestCPY4 WHERE t1.num = t2.num AND t1.dt = T2.DT AND t1.cd = t2.cd);
```

I would also consider whether you have any indexes on your table that it would pay off to DROP before you perform your DELETE, and REBUILD afterwards. For example, DELETING from a clustered columnstore index can be a very expensive operation. DELETING from a heap table is less expensive, and dropping and rebuilding a clustered columnstore index therefore often pays off.

That's all I can think of, based on the information you've provided. Hope it helps!